# wrap a callback function and a normal function into another callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

This section of code runs just fine....however, now I am trying to prevent the next line of code from running until the first one is done but am having a hard time figuring out how to code this:  *(my head is spinning in callback hell)*

Both functions work just fine, but checkRegister is executing before readFromFile has completed - I need readFromFile to complete first before checkRegister runs:

```
readFromFile('userdata.json', 0, yesFile(1), noFile(1051)) ;  //callback function
checkRegister() ;  // regular function
```

Comment: `readFromFile('userdata.json', 0, yesFile(1), noFile(1051), checkRegister)` and invoke the 5th argument in the `readFromFile` implementation after it's completed.

Comment: Where's the callback function in that `readFromFile` call? Can you maybe show us its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell what's the best approach without seeing the code for `readFromFile`, but you could pass your `checkRegister` as an argument to `readFromFile` and call it when it's done reading the file (callback):

```
readFromFile('userdata.json', 0, yesFile(1), noFile(1051), checkRegister)
```

Or use Promises and then you can chain your checkRegister function :

```
readFromFile('userdata.json', 0, yesFile(1), noFile(1051)).then(checkRegister)
```

Comment: I do like the promise option.  How can I do that with javascript (not jQuery) though.  I am trying to do: `var promise = new Promise(function` but then literally get stuck at there passing `readFromFile` into the resolve, (will come up with an empty error)...and then chain off of that.  will it be: `new Promise(function(readFromFile('userdata.json',0,yesFile(1),noFile(1051),error).then(checkRegister)`

Comment: @rolinger You will have to rewrite `readFromFile` to return a promise. Show us its code and we might be able to help you with that.